# FlashList is taking too long in first render compared to FlatList

Tags: javascript, react-native, shopify, react-native-flatlist, flash-list

### Current behavior

FlashList is taking too much time on first render compared to FlatList:
Flashlit is taking around 3 seconds
Flatlist is taking 300ms

### Expected behavior

FlashList should take not much time on first render.
for FlatList change only FlashList to Flatlist and remove estimatedItemSize and estimatedListSize

### To Reproduce

this is my code:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Dimensions, FlatList } from 'react-native';
import { NewCarCard } from 'features/cars/new-cars/new-car-card';
import { Line } from 'ui/dividers/line';
import { useNewCars } from 'features/cars/new-cars/hooks/use-new-cars';
import { NewCarsVerticalListShimmer } from 'features/cars/new-cars/shimmers/new-cars-vertical-list.shimmer';

const deviceWidth = Dimensions.get('window').width;
const deviceHeight = Dimensions.get('window').height;

interface Props {
  onPress: () => void;
  scrollEnabled: boolean;
}

export function NewCarsVerticalList(props: Props) {
  const { data, hasNextPage, fetchNextPage, isFetchingNextPage } = useNewCars();
  const newCarsFlatted = data?.pages.map(page => page.data.data.items).flat();
  const loadNext = React.useCallback(() => {
    if (hasNextPage && !isFetchingNextPage) {
      fetchNextPage();
    }
  }, [hasNextPage, isFetchingNextPage, fetchNextPage]);

  const renderItem = ({ item }) => {
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <NewCarCard newCar={item} onPress={props.onPress} />
        <Line />
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  };
  const renderListFooter = () => {
    if (isFetchingNextPage) {
      return (
        // Show shimmer when isFetchingNextPage is true
        <>
          <NewCarsVerticalListShimmer />
          <NewCarsVerticalListShimmer />
        </>
      );
    }
    return null;
  };

  return (
    <FlashList
      scrollEnabled={props.scrollEnabled || false}
      data={newCarsFlatted}
      showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
      estimatedItemSize={deviceHeight * 0.45}
      estimatedListSize={{
        height: deviceHeight * 0.45 * newCarsFlatted.length,
        width: Dimensions.get('screen').width,
      }}
      renderItem={({ item }) => renderItem({ item })}
      keyExtractor={item => item?.id} // Make sure to use a string for the key
      onEndReached={loadNext}
      onEndReachedThreshold={0.7}
      ListFooterComponent={renderListFooter}
    />
  );
}

export default React.memo(NewCarsVerticalList);
```

### Platform:

- iOS
- Android

### Environment

- "react-native": "0.72.3"
- "@shopify/flash-list": "^1.6.1",

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The right answer was:
estimatedListSize should refer to number of possible available items in the screen and not the whole dataset

```
estimatedListSize={{
        height: deviceHeight * 0.45 * newCarsFlatted.length,
        width: Dimensions.get('screen').width,
      }}
```

In my case only 2 elements of the list could be shown in screen.